# How can I find out a Latitude or Longitude at a distance of X from another latitude or Longitude?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to create a square bounding box around a coordinate(Lat,Long).

I need to "Add" a distance (say 5 km) to a Lat-Long for that first.

- Can I ignore projections for small grids of say 10 km sides?
- What is the biggest approximate square box for which I can ignore the spherical considerations?
- How can I add and subtract X kms (say 5) to a Latitude/Longitude (24.5,-88.65) to get the edges of the bounding box?

P.S. My work is in continental US, if it helps.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in general or how to do it with code?

Comment: Not really an R question. Looks like you are looking for geometry help (projection error etc)

Comment: @Takendarkk Question 3 is for code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the package`geosphere` there is a function called `destPoint()` which takes as inputs the initial location, the direction (angle in degrees) and the distance in meters. You can use this function twice, once for the horizontal direction and again for the vertical direction. For example:

```
library(geosphere)

# Starting longitude and latitude:
coords <- c(-71, 42)

# Distance in meters:
distance <- 5000

ne.coords <- c(destPoint(p = coords, b = 90, d = distance)[1],
               destPoint(p = coords, b = 0,  d = distance)[2])

sw.coords <- c(destPoint(p = coords, b = 90, d = -distance)[1],
               destPoint(p = coords, b = 0,  d = -distance)[2])
```

This gives:

```
R> ne.coords
[1] -70.93965  42.04502
R> sw.coords
[1] -71.06035  41.95498
```

Comment: Thank you, is this always travelling to the right (lat) and top (long)? For the bounding box, I would also have to calculate the bounding side for the opposide side of the square... How can I modify this for that? Basically coords+distance and coords-distance.

Comment: Also, here it says p should be in degrees. In the example you gave, DMS=Decimal. But if I want to use decimals (my data is in decimals), I have to convert first right?

Comment: I edited the answer to give you the South-West part of the box. You just have to use a negative distance. `p` should be in decimals, not DMS, so you don't need to convert.